# js array associative: indexOf is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

i don't know what's wrong with my code. Could you help me please?
This function is going to translate words using array.
The full taks is:

> Represent a small bilingual lexicon as a Javascript object in the
>   following fashion {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och",
>   "happy":gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"ĺr"} and use it to translate your
>   Christmas cards from English into Swedish.

```js
function translateText(){
var translate=[], i= 0,text, word, text2='';
    translate = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"ĺr"};

    text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    word = text.split(" ");


  for (i;i<word.length; i++){

      if (translate.indexOf(word)!==-1) {

          text2 += translate[word] + " ";

      }else{
          text2 += word + " ";

      }
  }

      document.getElementById('boxEight').innerHTML = text2;
}
```

Comment: you initially declare `translate` as an empty array, then overwrite it with an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object), which does not support `indexOf`. You can simply use `if (translate[word])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're using an *object* not an *array*, although objects can be used in a way similar to an array.

To check if an object contains a value, you can use [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
if (translate.hasOwnProperty(word)) {
  ...
}
```

[`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in):

```
if (word in translate) {
  ...
}
```

Or just a good old fashioned access, if you only care about it having a "truthy" value (not `0`, `false`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` or empty string).

```
if (translate[word]) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think it might be the fact that you converted your translate array into an object with the following line:

```
translate = {"merry":"god", "christmas":"jul", "and":"och", "happy":"gott", "new":"nytt", "year":"ĺr"};
```

Try changing curly braces{} to square brackets []

Comment: Changing the curly braces to square brackets would produce invalid JavaScript.

Comment: That's right Mike, forgot that associative arrays in JavaScript are used as objects

Comment: changing {} to [] doesn't work like Mike C commented few minutes ago

Answer (score -1):

you make translate an object, not an array, so first:

```
translate = [{"merry":"god"}, {"christmas":"jul"}, {"and":"och"}, {"happy":"gott"}, {"new":"nytt"}, {"year":"ĺr"}];
```

next, indexof is a method for getting the index of a word or character in a string
[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)